# Vector2 class in C++

Tags: c++, vector

In C++, is there a Vector2 class and if so, what do I need to include to use it?

I want to use this to store 2-dimensional vectors such as position or velocity of a particle.

Comment: Since when is position a 2-dimensional collection?

Comment: If you're working in a plane it is. Pretty clearly implied by the question.

Comment: Are you not rendering these particles? I'm sure whatever graphics library you're using will have a Vector2 object. SFML is a very nice cross-platform C++ multimedia library.

Answer (score 7):

Here you go.

```
struct Vector2
{
  float x;
  float y;
};
```

Or alternatively you can use `std::pair<float, float>`.

Then you'll want to learn more about Structure Of Arrays (SOA) vs Arrays of Structures (AOS) and how it impacts the performance of your code.

Particle systems would typically go SOA.

Finally here is a [series of blog posts on AOS & SOA applied to the implementation of a particle system](http://divergentcoder.com/programming/aos-soa-explorations-part-1/).

EDIT: there are nice math libraries out there like [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) or [glm](https://github.com/g-truc/glm) that would define such types for you along with many useful algorithms (with performant implementations).

Comment: Or `struct Point2 { ... }; typedef std::vector<Point2> Vector2`?

Comment: Using `std::pair<>` is not a very good idea here. `Vector2` says much more than `std::pair<>`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "vector2" class in the standard libraries. 
There is a pair class that would suit your needs, but for this scenario it would probable be best to create your own vector class(because then you get to have the variables named x and y, rather than first and second), e.g.

```
class Vector2
{
public:
   double x;
   double y;

   Vector2( double x, double y);
   ... etc
}
```

You can then overload the operator +, add functions for finding cross/dot product, etc.

The std::vector class is NOT what you need. The std::vector class is pretty much just a replacement for C malloced arrays.

Comment: no, don't overload `operator +` etc. unless you implement them using expression templates, your code will be slowed down by the generation of many temporaries

Comment: @Gregory: I don't see how performance would suffer from temporaries here. OTOH, vector arithmetic without (sensible) overloaded operators will look like hell.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`std::pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/) in the header `<utility>`. It doesn't support vector arithmetic, though.